# Groovy Script Send Multipart Request to Grails Web App for test

Tags: grails, groovy, gradle, multipart

I'm trying to test my Grails web application by creating and sending a multipart request from a stand-alone groovy test script that's built by gradle. But I'm struggling.

- I can't attach a custom Content-ID header
- I can't attach a file of random bytes created at runtime (I can attach an existing file, but I need many random files of varying size)

**EDIT (Thanks to Xeon):**

- My script is now sending a valid multipart request, but my grails web app is not accepting any headers other than "Content-Type" for some reason.

Heres my code:

The Stand-Alone Test Script code:

```
void sendMultipartRequest(String url) {
    HTTPBuilder httpBuilder = new HTTPBuilder(url)
    httpBuilder.request(Method.POST){ req ->

        MultipartEntityBuilder entityBuilder = new MultipartEntityBuilder()
        entityBuilder.setBoundary("----boundary")

        entityBuilder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.RFC6532)

        String randomString = myGenerateRandomStringMethod()
        FormBodyPart formBodyPart = new FormBodyPart(
            "SOME_NAME", 
            new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(randomString.bytes), "attachment", "SOME_NAME")
        )
        formBodyPart.addField("Content-ID", "abc123")
        entityBuilder.addPart(formBodyPart)

        response.success = { resp ->
            println("Success with response ${resp.toString()}")
        }
        response.failure = { resp ->
            println("Failure with response ${resp.toString()}")
        }

        delegate.setHeaders(["Content-Type":"multipart/related; boundary=----boundary"])
        req.setEntity(entityBuilder.build())
    }
}
```

Grails web-app side in the controller for handling posts:

```
def submitFiles() {
    if(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest){
        HashMap<String, Byte[]> fileMap = extractMultipartFiles(request)
        someService.doStuffWith(fileMap)
    }
}
private HashMap<String, Byte[]> extractMultipartFiles(MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest) {
    HashMap<String, Byte[]> files = new HashMap<>()
    for(element in mulipartRequest.multiFileMap){
        MultipartFile file = element.value.first()
        String contentId = multipartRequest.getMultipartHeaders(element.key).get("Content-ID")?.first()
        if(contentId) files.put(contentId, file.getBytes())
    }
    return files
}
```

Libraries I'm using:

```
ext {
    groovyVersion = "2.3.4"
    commonsLangVersion = "2.6"
    httpBuilderVersion = "0.7.1"
    httpmimeVersion = "4.3.4"
    junitVersion = "4.11"
}
dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:${groovyVersion}"
    compile "commons-lang:commons-lang:${commonsLangVersion}"
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:${httpBuilderVersion}"
    compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:${httpmimeVersion}"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: "${junitVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use some subclass of `ContentBody` interface:

```
FormBodyPart(String name, ContentBody body)
```

For example use: `InputStreamBody`:

```
new FormBodyPart("name", new InputStreamBody(new RandomInputStream(...)), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
```

You can use: [RandomInputStream](http://jakubstas.com/random-generated-input-stream) class.

And with headers you could probably use: `HTTPBuilder$RequestConfigDelegate.setHeaders(Map headers)` because it's set to delegate of inner closure.

Comment: Thanks!!! I don't have RandomInputStream available to me, so what I used was: new FormBodyPart("name", new InputStreamBody(new ByteArrayInputStream(randomString.bytes), "attachment", "name")). This added the string as an attached file rather than a parameter.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use the RequestConfigDelegate though, could you maybe give an example? It looks like RequestConfigDelegate is a static sub class of HTTPBuilder, but how would I set the headers for an individual multipart file with it?

Comment: @SnoopDougg as far as I know it a delegate and the method is public - so you should be able to invoke it directly or by `delegate.setHeaders()`.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, it's still not working for me :( I've updated my question above with an EDIT to show what I've tried...

Comment: I think I've found the problem - the Content-Type of MultipartEntityBuilder.build() is set to "multipart/form-data" by default. But in order for the Content-ID header to be included, the Content-Type of the post has to be "multipart/related"... Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way to do this... any suggestions?

Comment: Ahhh. Nevermind. I used TCPMon to see what my multipart request looked like, and it's valid. The error must be in my grails web app. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've used curl in the past to do this testing:

```
curl -v -F "param1=1" -F "param2=99" -F "fileparam=@somefile.flv;type=video/x-flv" http://localhost:8080/someapp/sessions
```

somefile.flv is in the current directory